# Convert NSString into NSDIctionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string ------ NSString abc = @"apple:87,banana:32,grapes:54";

i need this output like this

```
{
    name = "apple";
    value = "87";
},
{
    name = "banana";
    value = "32";
},
{
    name = "grapes";
    value = "54";
}
```

I have tried:

```
NSArray* itemList = [abc componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString* item in itemList) {
    NSArray* subItemList = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    if (subItemList.count > 0) {
       [dict setObject:[subItemList objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[subItemList objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

The output is --

```
{ 
    apple = 87;
    banana = 32;
    grapes = 54;
}
```

but i dont want this output

Comment: NSArray* itemList = [abc componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (NSString* item in itemList)
        {
            NSArray* subItemList = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
            if (subItemList.count > 0){
                [dict setObject:[subItemList objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[subItemList objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", dict);



but i dont want this output----

Comment: Please add code in the question, not comments. Your code would seem to be exactly what you want. But your title describes what you want as a log of a dictionary, and I think what you really mean is that you want an array of dictionaries?

Comment: I think you need to be more clear in your problem. What output is that you don't want? Do you want a NSDictionary or you want a string like the first you wrote (like JSON style with '=' and ';' instead of ':' and ','?

Comment: @eric What output are you currently getting? And what output do you actually want?

Comment: You went to some effort to write code that doesn't do what you want. Except from the check that subItemList.count > 0 which should be > 1, that code looks fine. So why don't you just change it to do what you want? In case you just copied it from the interwebs, take some time to understand what the code does.

Comment: @LyndseyScott -- wain already edited my question..please read the my question again...well i got my answer..thanks :)

Comment: @eric I saw the edit already. I'm asking what output are you currently getting with the NSLog? And what output do you actually want?

Comment: @eric Nevermind. I see you accepted the answer. So you were in fact creating a dictionary, but wanted an array.

Comment: @LyndseyScott -- yeah..exactly

Comment: If you want an array of dictionaries why don't you create an array of dictionaries?  You create a dictionary and expect it to magically turn into an array?

Comment: Caution, blatantly off topic: Incredible to see a lady around here! Keep it up :) @LyndseyScott [I love people breaking stereo-types! So please don't take this sexist.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wanted output is a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.

So:

```
NSArray* itemList = [abc componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; 
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *aString in itemList)
{
    NSArray* subItem = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"name":[subItem objectAtIndex:0], 
                           @"value":[subItem objectAtIndex:1]};
    [finalArray addObject:dict];
}
```

I didn't use the `if ([subItem count] > 0)`, trying just to keep the logic you missed and clarify the algorithm.

I didn't test the code, but that should do it. (or maybe a little compiler error easy to correct).

Comment: `subItem[0]` and `[1]` would have been even clearer, though the answer is already excellent.

Comment: @Tommy: I didn't want to use the short hand syntax for `NSArray` (`objectAtIndex:` equivalent) since there was already a confusion about the structure of the wanted output, keep shorthand syntax only for `NSDictionary` items. I think that this short hand syntax confuse people who may already be encline to have issue with "What object I'm manipulating?", but that's a personal opinion.

Comment: @Larme well, we disagree on that. `array[item]` is the ordinary syntax is a huge number of languages; I'd therefore argue that it's much less confusing than having the real mechanics of the thing spelt out fully. But whatever. Your answer got my vote already; I'm quibbling over nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants the equivalent in Swift:

```
let abc = "apple:87,banana:32,grapes:54"

let dict = abc.componentsSeparatedByString(",").map { pair -> [String: String] in
    let parts = pair.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    return ["name": parts[0], "value": parts[1]]
}
```